# Calculate Rolling Return/Moving Average using Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, moving-average, rolling-computation

I download daily adjusted price data for the companies 'AAPL','BA','GS', and the DJIA index from yahoo finance between the date '12/31/2008' and '12/31/2018' and then convert into daily returns based on Adj. Close.

```
# Download price data
import pandas as pd  
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
yf.pdr_override() 
import datetime 

start_dt = datetime.datetime(2008, 12, 31)
end_dt = datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 31)

def getDataBatch(tickers, startdate, enddate):
  def getData(ticker):
    return (pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start=startdate, end=enddate))
  datas = map(getData, tickers)
  return(pd.concat(datas, keys=tickers, names=['Ticker', 'Date']))

data_AAPL = pdr.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', start=start_dt, end=end_dt)
data_BA = pdr.get_data_yahoo('BA', start=start_dt, end=end_dt)
data_GS = pdr.get_data_yahoo('GS', start=start_dt, end=end_dt)
data_DJIA = pdr.get_data_yahoo('^DJI', start=start_dt, end=end_dt)

#Convert into daily return
def getReturns(tickers, start_dt, end_dt, freq): 
    px_data = getDataBatch(tickers, start_dt, end_dt)
    px = px_data[['Adj Close']].reset_index().pivot(index='Date', columns='Ticker', values='Adj Close')
    if (freq=='daily'):
        px = px.resample('D').last()
    ret = px.pct_change().dropna()
    ret.columns = tickers
    return(ret)

Ticker_List = ['AAPL','BA','GS','^DJI']
ReturnData = getReturns(Ticker_List, start_dt, end_dt, freq='daily')
ReturnData.columns = ['AAPL','BA','GS','DJIA']
```

I want to calculate rolling annual returns for the 3 stocks and DJIA using a **for loop** by looping through 252 daily data points each time and saving the results into a new variable.

I know that how to use a Rolling Function but I'm not sure how to use a for loop to do the same thing. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Why do you insist on using a for-loop? A for-loop will just be much, much slower. The usual way is to use a convolution with a rectangular window, or `pandas.rolling_mean`.

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree pandas.rolling_mean is much easier and quicker, but using a for-loop is my professor's requirement. I need to use multiple ways to do the same thing.

Comment: It's a bit weird to use a huge library like `pandas`, but then restrict the usage of its functions. Anyway, try to write a convolution as a for-loop. For a rectangular window with sum==1 you can then simplify the convolution considerably.